# What is the best way to optimise this list traversing function? instead of doing nested for loops?

Tags: c++

How do you optimise this function that traverses the same list with nested for loops to find if there are two items when summed up results in the target sum? This implementation works but I would ideally like to not do nested loops.

```
std::pair<int, int> getTargetSumIndices(std::vector &list, int targetSum)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < list.size(); k++)
        {
            if(i != k) 
            {
                int sum = list[i] + list[k];
                if(sum == targetSum) return std::make_pair(i, k);
            }
        }
    }

    return std::make_pair(-1, -1);
}

void main() 
{
    std::vector<int> list = {0, 3, 5, 6, 6, 2, 8};
    std::pair<int, int> indices = getTargetSumIndices(list, 10);        
}
```

Comment: Is this a coding puzzle from one of the many web sites that offer random coding puzzles, claiming that doing them turns anyone into a C++ uberhacker, and is the shown code getting rejected because of "time limit exceeded", and you think that means it must be optimized? No, that's not what that means. It means the direct approach by brute force, this entire algorithm, is wrong. You need to figure out the correct fundamental algorithm that needs to be used here. Unfortunately you won't find it on the web site this puzzle is from, but only in a good computer science and algorithms textbook.

Comment: I think that by sorting data, one can figure out a way to do it in O(n log n) instead of O(n²). You could check each number as you fill a `set` or you can sort the whole data and then check it in a smart way...

Comment: @Phil1970 Agree. It's actually pretty trivial with a sorted list.

Answer (score 1):

Base on the comments posted by @Phil1970 and @doug I performed a sort and then improved the recursion to achieve this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>

std::pair<int, int> getTargetSumIndices(std::vector<int> &list, int targetSum)
{
    std::sort(list.begin(), list.begin() + list.size());
    int start = 0;
    int end = list.size() - 1;
    
    while(start < end)
    {
        if (list[start] + list[end] == targetSum) 
        {   
            return std::make_pair(start, end); 
        }
        else if (list[start] + list[end] < targetSum) 
            start++; 
        else 
            end--; 
    }

    return std::make_pair(-1, -1);
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> list = {0, 3, 5, 6, 6, 2, 8};
    std::pair<int, int> indices = getTargetSumIndices(list, 10);
    
    std::cout << indices.first << ", " << indices.second << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That code will fails if the list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do lots of queries, or the size of list is very big, creating a map for list is worth it. The code is as follows.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<unordered_map>

std::pair<int, int> getTargetSumIndices(std::vector<int> &list, int targetSum)
{
    std::unordered_multimap<int, int> listmap;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
        listmap.insert(std::pair<int,int>(list[i], i));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
        auto its = listmap.equal_range(targetSum - list[i]);
        for (auto itor = its.first; itor != its.second; ++itor) {
            if (i != itor->second) {
                return std::make_pair(i, itor->second);
            }
        }
    }

    return std::make_pair(-1, -1);
}

void main()
{
    std::vector<int> list = { 0, 3, 5, 6, 6, 2, 8 };
    std::pair<int, int> indices = getTargetSumIndices(list, 10);
}
```

I notice that variable 'list' contains some repeated elements, so I use multimap here.
However, if your data size is not very bog, or you don't do queries frequently, the nested loops is much better, since the construction of hash map also costs time.
Besides, the code you provide can also be improved, you can change the nested loop, and get rid of `if(i!=k)`. Like this:

```
for(int k=i+1;k<list.size();++k)
```

Comment: As you only need to return one pair, your code could be simplified a lot and you can get at least a 2× speed improvement.

Comment: There is no specific problems were introduced, input and output are not explained clearly. So it's just an example, mainly to introduce the idea of hashing. Of course you can make any adjustments you want to suit specific problems.

Comment: In terms of my code regardless of the problem, it actually can be improved. When I write the code, I was confused about the output of this problem, so something molimen appeared in my code. You can regard it just as an introduce of the idea of hashing.